# Publish Azure function app URL is unreachable

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions

I have published function apps plenty of times before without issue. But today a new function app is throwing this when publishing from Visual Studio 2022:

```
The Publish URL https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/ is unreachable. The application may be stopped, restarting or unavailable. Try again once the publish target is available.
```

If I paste that URL into a browser is opens the Kudu page just fine.

The function app is definitely running, but I have tried restarting it also.

If I try publishing another function app in the same VS solution, that works fine too. It's just this one for some reason?

Comment: Can you share the function code which you tried? which error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> function app is throwing this when publishing from Visual Studio 2022:
> The Publish URL https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/ is unreachable. The application may be stopped, restarting or unavailable. Try again once the publish target is available.

AFAIK, there could be misconfigurations in your App settings that are preventing access to the URL. Double-check your settings to ensure everything is configured correctly. check below:

[image]

I have created Http trigger function with runtime stack dotnet in visual studio.
The Http trigger function runs successfully in my local environment. check below:

[image]

- I have created function app in azure portal with dotnet runtime stack and windows operating system.
- I tried below steps to publish the Function into azure portal.
  Right click on the solution name and follow below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- I have published the function successfully into azure portal and it will be able to see in portal. check below:

[image]

- The Http trigger function successfully runs in azure portal. check below:

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: You were correct about the misconfiguration, but it was in General Settings: SCM Basic Auth Publishing was turned off